# Biztalk 2010 Pipeline encoding problem?

Tags: encoding, biztalk

I have a flat-file which get's converted to a wrong charset. Where in a pipeline, if you use a flat file dissambler can you change the encoding? 
Or what else to do?

Comment: FixEncoding component: http://winterdom.com/2006/01/fixmessageencodingcustompipelinecomponentsample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error you are getting?

You can change the encoding used during flat file disassembly by setting the CodePage property in your flat file schema.

Further to that an algorithm is applied to work out the encoding object to use during disassembly:

- If the Charset in the Message body part is set, its value is used.
- Otherwise, if the envelope (or document) schema specifies a code page
  using the Code Page property, its value is used.
- Otherwise, if a byte order mark is present, its value is used.
- Otherwise, assume UTF-8.

Comment: I have flatfiles incoming which get's special characters (å,ä,ö) in wrong encoding.

Comment: So are you still having problems then? Did you see @Derek's suggestion in his comment above?